# Turn on QGIS Dark Mode

Tags: qgis

How do you turn on the dark mode for QGIS 3.6.1? I see where people have an option in the general settings of the Project Properties menu, but I am not seeing that option in my version.

Comment: You don't have the option under Settings > General > UI Theme > Night Mapping?

Comment: That was it! I was looking in the project properties menu.

Comment: Another alternative is this plugin https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/LoadQSS/! You don't need to restart! DISCLAIMER: I'm the author

Answer (score 46, accepted):

When you open `Settings->Options->General` you should see `Night Mapping`.

[image]

You need to exit and restart to see the change.

Comment: This works well for my Windows machine, although does not appear to work with my Mac. I'm running 3.10.4 on both machines.